# libssh: ssh_is_host_known called without cryptographic context

Tags: c, ssh, cryptography, libssh

I was trying to include SSH communication into my program using libssh 0.7.0. I followed the tutorial to create a simple connection to a remote machine but I came across this error:

```
[2016/10/26 16:38:56.280261, 1] ssh_is_server_known:  ssh_is_host_known called without cryptographic context
```

After searching the source code of the library and its documentation, I didn't find anything related to this "lack" of cryptographic context that could help solving the issue.

Here's the code I'm trying to execute (it's part of a function; IP address and user are not the actual ones):

```
ssh_session session;
int verbosity = SSH_LOG_PROTOCOL;
int port = 22;
int state;

ssh_init();

session = ssh_new();
if (session == NULL){
    printf("Failed to create SSH session\n"); return NULL;
}

ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_HOST, "111.111.111.111");
ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_USER, "user");
ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_LOG_VERBOSITY, &verbosity);
ssh_options_set(session, SSH_OPTIONS_PORT, &port);

state = ssh_is_server_known(session);
if(state != SSH_SERVER_KNOWN_OK){
    printf("SSH Server is not known\n");
}
```

(I tried to execute this section without calling `ssh_init()` but the error occurred on both cases).

Comment: the link to your tutorial would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [tour (tutorial) on official page](http://api.libssh.org/master/libssh_tutor_guided_tour.html), you need to connect to the server, before verifying that the server is known (the server needs to send you its host key). Therefore add a

```
rc = ssh_connect(my_ssh_session);
if (rc != SSH_OK)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to localhost: %s\n",
            ssh_get_error(my_ssh_session));
    exit(-1);
}
```

before checking `ssh_is_server_known()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As expected, it solved the issue ;) I didn't notice that the code of the tutorial I was trying to execute wasn't the actual main function but a function called after connecting to the server..